# How do i group the users in Thread Group & create users in apache jmeter?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, jmeter, load-testing, performance-testing

In my project(its a web based application), i need to test load performance test for 20 web pages. 
I have a confusion that how  do i know :
when i need to create next Thread (user) Group ? and
How many HTTP Request (pages) i should create inside a Thread Group ?

Description of Image :
[i took four Thread Group 
User1,User2,User3 & User4
& created two or three HTTP Request(web pages) inside each Thread(user) Group ]

[image]

I want to know am i following the right process for creation of Users & Thread Groups?
Is it a right process? cause i was getting errors(HttpHostConnectionException) in some pages..

please someone suggest me what is the correct process?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jmeter is an excellent tool for Performance testing and Functional testing (not for UI validation).
It is really easy to learn and anyone can become master in it. Before creating the test plan, try to understand learn what each element is for & what it does exactly.

**Thread Group:**

- It is a set which simulates the number of user(s) to your server application
- As far as I know, there is no limit for samplers/elements inside a Thread Group.

Lets consider this scenario.

In a web based application, 10 users login and order new products again and again, 10 support users login and update existing products in the same time.

So, In this case, I might create 2 thread groups. One for ordering products and other one for updating existing products. 'No of Threads/Users' for each thread Group should be set to 10.

**Sampler:**

Each sampler is a request to the server. If you need to hit 20 different pages, you need to have 20 samplers. As it is a web based application, you should add HTTP samplers under a thread group.

**Listener:**

(As per apache) A listener is a component that shows the results of the samples. 
You have added a listener for each sampler. This is not correct. You need to have that in the test plan level. (atleast Thread Group level)

Please refer to the tutorials below.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mfFSrxpl0Y

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jmeter/jmeter_build_test_plan.htm

& Ofcourse,

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/

Comment: @vlns - Thanks for replying !You are saying that for each sampler we should not add a listener. but i want to know why we should not? if we want to see performance result of each sampler then we can see from it.Can you explain once.I really want to know why this is incorrect.

Comment: You can add. But You do not need it. See, these listeners consume a lot of system memory. So you should not add for each sampler. The result you get might not be a realistic. You need a listener in a test plan level to see the total requests sent and the response you got for each sampler, time taken etc... As a friendly advice, i had shared the tutorials, please go thro, you will get some idea. You can always ask here if you have any questions. 

Please see here for some more tips.

http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips

Answer (score 2):

Thread is a simulation of a real user in JMeter and thus threadgroup contains actions done by user.

Practically there is no limit of samplers/requests in a threadgroup but for our simplicity,readability and for debugging purpose it is recommended that one should divide the requests into logically seperated sections. for seperating requests you have 2 options,

1. `Threadgroup` : Its a component in JMeter for which threads are defined, rampup is defined i.e. it has its own properties which will be shared by all samplers under it. `In real life it represents a process comprising of many short workflows`. for example when I say workflow I mean login,shop something,add into cart,pay the money,logout (short actions by users) and when I process it means "buy a product" which include all above

I hope this have cleared distinction between process and workflow

2. `Transaction controller` : Its a small version of Threadgroup which uses properties of Threadgroup i.e. its parent threadgroup. it is generally used to seperate requests/samplers which are part of single process. i.e. It is used to seperate login,buy product etc. products which are part of single threadgroup

Finally, Threadgroups should be used for a process which we would like to load test "**Test `buy a product` with 10 users**"

Transaction controller should be used for a workflow "**login workflow and pay money**"

below diagram should help,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering @Nachiket Kate . You reply helped me.